# how to deploy mdf file/ linq-to-sql classes

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, deployment

I worte an application based on oop layer , I have 4 C3 projects, PL (presentaion layer) as windows service I have BL (businnes logic) projects copiled as DLL and I  have :

1) BE (businnes Elements) I used Linq to Sql Classes and also copiled it to DLL
2) DAL (Data Acces layer) I have mdf file that have al the classe drom the BE as tabels.

My question is - I deploy  that solution in another server and when it try to read from the sql it get an error:

An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file F:\Users\Abramovitch\Desktop\FinalProject\RSA-Manager\RSA-Manager\bin\Debug\RSA-DB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

**What should I insert in the AttachDbFilename ptoperty??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLServer (MDF Files) is not a single file database that you can move as you wish.
At least you need to install on the other server SQL Server with compatible version and try to attach your file.

Comment: and how should I attach my file to it? as it cpiled to DLL

Comment: From your updated question, it seems that your 'other server' is trying to connect to your machine. Of course this is possibile only if you give the relevant permissions to the other user. You should explain better your working scenario. Where is your database?. It's a single user solution or a client-server one?.That's not clear to me.